# google colab pytorch version error (course 231n)

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, cs231n

I'm going through cs231n exercises. Now I have a problem with it!
In assignment 2 in PyTorch.ipynb (The link of the file : https://github.com/israfelsr/CS231n/blob/master/assignment2/PyTorch.ipynb)
As usual, I run the first cell which mounts the drive and in the second cell it checks PyTorch version to be 1.4 by using assert command in python. That's where the error comes out. Does anybody know why this is happening and how can I fix that?

[image]
first cell

[image]
A Bit of information. It says if you're in colab you don't need to do anything

[image]
The second cell where it asserts to check PyTorch version is 1.4 and it's not and so shows error.
For more information please refer to the GitHub link I provided above.